# Azure Storage Static Website using old code

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-static-web-app

I updated my static website files few times, but the website is still showing old code, even if I deleted everything from my browser / using incognito. I'm not using Azure CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround until Microsoft hires some testers: 
Azure Storage - Static Website -> Disable -> Enable.